# AWS S3 getObject is not able to read object content through PHP SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried to read content from a s3 object through the below code.

```
$content = $s3Client->getObject(
                        array(
                            'Bucket'=> $bucketName,
                            'Key' =>  $pathToObject,
                            'ResponseContentType' => 'text/plain',
                        )
                    );
```

And I got below response

> GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object (
>       [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #87
>       [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
>       [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
>       [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
>       [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
>       [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
>       [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
>           (
>           )
>
> )

Any help will be appreciated to read object content in S3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually its return Psr7\Stream object.

So if we need to get contents from PSR Stream we have to call getContents() method from the object.

```
<?php

$s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client(array(
    'stats'   => TRUE,
    'http'    => array(
        'verify' => FALSE,
        'connect_timeout' => 30
    ),
    'version'     => 'latest'
));     

$result = $s3Client->getObject(array(
    'Key'    => $filename,
    'Bucket' => $bucketName
));

echo $result['Body']->getContents();
//Also you can get metadata like this print_r($result['Body']->getMetadata());
```

Hope this will help someone who is actually using SDK version 3.

Specification here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-GuzzleHttp.Psr7.Stream.html

Comment: Remember that 'Body' is case sensitive. I hadn't caught that, and it took me too long to realize my mistake!